# For loop over selected rows

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R (or any programming language) I want to run a for loop along a selected rows of a Matrix, say 3,5,6,8. I know how to do it for a continuous range.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
my_mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)
my_seq <- c(3, 5, 6, 8)

for(i in my_seq) {

  print(my_mat[i, ])

}
```